# Ways of making polite numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Given that $n$ is a [polite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number), meaning that it can be expressed as the sum of two or more consecutive positive integers, how many different ways are there to express $n$ as the sum of at least two consecutive positive integers? Can you prove that the method you describe works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you linked to answers your question:

> The politeness of a positive number is defined as the number of ways it can be expressed as the sum of consecutive integers. For every x, the politeness of x equals the number of odd divisors of x that are greater than one.

...

> An easy way of calculating the politeness of a positive number is that of decomposing the number into its prime factors, taking the powers of all prime factors greater than 2, adding 1 to all of them, multiplying the numbers thus obtained with each other and subtracting 1.

I guess I'll say a word or two about why looking at odd divisors works.  If $x$ is a sum of an odd number $k$ of consecutive positive integers with average term $d$, then $x=kd$.  Conversely, if $k>1$ is an odd divisor of $x$, and $x=kd$ with $d-\frac{k-1}{2} > 0$, then $x$ is the sum of $k$ consecutive integers with average term $d$.  For example, if $x=6$, then this process relates the odd divisor $k=3$ of $x$ with the three-term sum centered at $d=\frac{6}{3}=2$, namely $6=1+2+3$.

It seems like we need a different bijection for sums of an *even* number of consecutive positive integers.  But actually, we can force the same bijection to work anyway, just by canceling all the negative terms.  For example, if $x=27$ and $k=9$, then we naively get a nine-term sum centered at $d=\frac{27}{9}=3$, namely $27 = (-1)+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7$.  But throwing away the first three terms gives us $27=2+3+4+5+6+7$.  So this even-length sum corresponds to the odd divisor $9$ of $27$.

Comment: Why does that work?

Comment: @user112829 Also answered on the linked page.

Comment: Heh, actually I added the link.  For clarity.  I think J.W. Perry gave the same link in a comment, now removed.

Comment: @hardmath It should have been an answer, apparently :)

Comment: I see by your hat that you are quick!

Comment: @user112829 I added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section **Politeness** here [Politeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number#Politeness)